# how to override AbstractCarrierOnline class function in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipping, override-model, abstract-class

I want to override "proccessAdditionalValidation" function of app/code/Magento/Shipping/Model/Carrier/AbstractCarrierOnline.php file in custom module.

Please help me and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you can use [**Plugin**](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html#before-methods.) as `proccessAdditionalValidation` is plugin method. You can use **before or after or around** as per as requirement.

**Create *di.xml* at `app/code/{Vendor}/{Modulename}/etc`** and where you define plugin class.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrierOnline">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="StackExchange_MagentoTest_Plugin_Magento_Shipping_Model_Carrier_AbstractCarrierOnline" sortOrder="10" type="StackExchange\MagentoTest\Plugin\Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrierOnline"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

And **Plugin** class located at `app/code/{Vendor}/{Modulename}/Plugin/Magento/Shipping/Model/Carrier/AbstractCarrierOnline.php`

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace StackExchange\MagentoTest\Plugin\Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier;

class AbstractCarrierOnline
{

    public function afterProccessAdditionalValidation(
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrierOnline $subject,
        $result,
        $request
    ) {
        // write your logic
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To override the **proccessAdditionalValidation** function of `/app/code/Magento/Shipping/Model/Carrier/AbstractCarrierOnline.php`

In your custom module, add below code in your `di.xml` file to override the model class.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrierOnline" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrierOnline" />
</config>
```

where `<preference for="">` is which Model to override and `<preference type="">` for where to override.

Now, create the **AbstractCarrierOnline.php** file under `Vendor\Module\Model\Carrier\` in your module.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Carrier;

class AbstractCarrierOnline extends \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrierOnline
{
    public function proccessAdditionalValidation()
    {
        //Add your code
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for reply